# Azure Data Explorer: Multi-Select Parameter "Select All" return all possible options instead

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

In Azure Data Explorer (dashboards, accessed via the web at the URL: dataexplorer.azure.com/dashboards/ ), a multi-select parameter will return empty (isempty() == true) if the "Select All" option is picked. However, I need to know all of the options if the "select all" option is picked. Is there a way to do this?

Here is an example of my Kusto query that the multiselect parameter feeds into. You will see that the "in" filter means I need a complete list of all of the options / values of the multiselect param.

```
Events
| where FilteredItem in (_multiselectParameter)
| where Timestamp between(_startTime.._endTime)
| summarize event_count = count() by bin(Timestamp, make_timespan(_timeSpan))
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you please clarify - what UX you're using? Different clients may have different ways of sending the UX-element info into queries.

Comment: I'm a user and am a little newer to the interface. This is the base URL that I am accessing: https://dataexplorer.azure.com/dashboards
Does that answer the question to which UX I am using?

Answer (score 3):

The way to write the Where clause, taking into consideration the "Select All" options is as follows:

```
| where FilteredItem in (_multiselectParameter) or isempty(_multiselectParameter)
```